# How to put custom data into a mongodb document with aldeed:autoform and aldeed:collection2?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I need to put some custom data into a `MongoDB` document with the two meteor packages `aldeed:autoform` and `aldeed:collection2`. I only know how to put fields like strings and numbers in the simple schema from `collection2`, but how would I put in a radio button that is on a lot of fields. To put in some context, I want to have a db that holds values for the user's favorite game. I want the user to be able to search the game title and then when they see it, press a radio button on it and have that value entered into the db. I have the search part done, but how to I put a radio button on that result from the search?

Comment: `aldeed:autoform` has a huge documentation: [link](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#affieldinput)

Comment: and a cool playground with all sorts of examples : http://autoform.meteorapp.com/